# C# Com Selenium - Duvida sobre xPath

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou automatizando uma função da página e quando ele vai clicar na imagem da erro, enfim já tentei varias coisas, minha duvida é a seguinte o xPath que estou enviando está correto?

```
<div id="toolbar">
        <table cellspacing="1px" cellpadding="1px" width="100%" class="birtviewer_toolbar">
            <tbody><tr><td></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="6px">
                </td><td width="15px">
                   <input type="image" name="toc" src="birt/images/Toc.gif" title="Comutar índice" alt="Comutar índice" class="birtviewer_clickable">
                </td>
                <!--
                <TD WIDTH="6px"/>
                <TD WIDTH="15px">
                   <INPUT TYPE="image" NAME='parameter' SRC="birt/images/Report_parameters.gif"
                        TITLE="Executar relatório"  
                        ALT="Executar relatório" CLASS="birtviewer_clickable">
                </TD>
                <TD WIDTH="6px"/>
                <TD WIDTH="15px">
                   <INPUT TYPE="image" NAME='export' SRC="birt/images/Export.gif"
                        TITLE="Exportar dados"
                        ALT="Exportar dados" CLASS="birtviewer_clickable">
                </TD>
                -->
                <td width="6px">
                </td><td width="15px">
                   <input type="image" name="exportReport" src="birt/images/ExportReport.gif" title="Exportar relatório" alt="Exportar relatório" class="birtviewer_clickable">
                </td>
                <td width="6px">
                </td><td width="15px">
                   <input type="image" name="print" src="birt/images/Print.gif" title="Imprimir relatório" alt="Imprimir relatório" class="birtviewer_clickable">
                </td>

                <td align="right">
                </td>
                <td width="6px">
            </td></tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
```

Classe que preciso clicar

```
  </td><td width="15px">
               <input type="image" name="exportReport" src="birt/images/ExportReport.gif" title="Exportar relatório" alt="Exportar relatório" class="birtviewer_clickable">
            </td>
```

xPath`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[./img[@name='exportReport']tr[2]/td[4]/]")).Click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certamente seu XPath não esta certo e esta retornando null.

Uma forma que você pode fazer é o seguinte.

```
var inputs = browser.FindElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (var item in inputs)
{
    var alt = item.GetAttribute("src");
    if (alt != null && alt.Contains("Exportar relatório"))
    {
        item.Click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: encontrou o elemento inputs ? ou teve algum erro?

Comment: retornou null no elemento input

Comment: fiz a depuração passo a passo, percorri 28x o foreach retornou ID, porem não chegou a entrar no if, não localizando o elemento src

Comment: você tem que depurar e vê como o item esta sendo carregado, vejas outras propriedades do elemento para ver se encontro o correto.

Comment: fiz o mapeamento, localizei uma Frame, entrei dentro da frame e consegui usar o src obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Seu HTML está mal formado. Tem que colocar terminações de tag nas tags INPUT.

O XPath que você procura é:

```
//input[@type='image'][@name='exportReport']
```